# Mod Rewrite Directory Checking

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a situation where I have several clients, each of which I'd like to be able to access their site via mydomain.com/clientname.  To keep things organized, I store the actual files for the client's sites in /client/clientname.  I can achieve the desired effect by putting lots and lots of these lines in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^client1(.*)$ /client/client1$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^client2(.*)$ /client/client2$1 [L]
```

etc.

I'm trying to do this in a cleaner way, by checking if the client directory exists in /client or not.  (If I've determined that it's not an otherwise valid file or directory).  But for some reason this seems to not be working:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond /client/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /client/$1 [L,QSA]
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Apache mod_rewrite docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html):

**REQUEST_FILENAME**

The **full local filesystem path to the file or script matching the request**, if this has already been determined by the server at the time REQUEST_FILENAME is referenced. Otherwise, such as when used in virtual host context, the same value as REQUEST_URI.

Your line:

```
RewriteCond /client/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
```

seems to cause the problem, because it makes Apache look for the following file path:

```
/client/[the whole filesystem path of requested file]
```

which is quite sure not what you want.

You may correct it as follows:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/client%{REQUEST_URI} -d
```

Comment: Exactly it!  Thanks.  Unfortunately, it's clear to me that this won't be that easy.  Since I have thinks like /client/orders (which is NOT a directory) I'll need to do some tricky things on the request URI if I want to check against a directory

Comment: @epalla I'm not sure I got the point, you can try RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/client%{REQUEST_URI} -f (instead of -d).

Comment: I've created a followup question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115775/rewrite-condition-to-compare-top-level-directory-from-request-uri

Comment: @epalla I answered to that question :)