# Rewrite Condition to compare top level directory from Request_URI

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have several clients on my website with largely similar sites setup for each client.  The folders for these client accounts are set up for organizational purposes at:

```
mydomain.com/client/sampleclient
mydomain.com/client/anotherclient
```

etc.

I want them to be able to access their content at simply /sampleclient or /anotherclient though.  To accomplish this, I've added this rule to my root .htaccess (Thanks to [Paolo Stefan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6112387/mod-rewrite-directory-checking)):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/client/%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /client/$1 [L,QSA]
```

This works well in redirecting the root directory.  IE, mydomain.com/sampleclient redirects perfectly to mydomain.com/client/sampleclient.  However, it doesn't work for requests within the client directories.  Something like:

```
mydomain.com/sampleclient/orders
```

Checks to see if client/sampleclient/orders is a directory, which it isn't (I'm using separate url rewriting within the client directories), so the rule is not applied.  Is there a way to apply a regular expression to the REQUEST_URI or something so that I ONLY check whether the top-level directory of the request_uri exists before applying the rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RewriteCond` can have a part of the match as its first argument, so you can use

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/client/$1 -d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/(.*)$ /client/$1/$2 [L,QSA]
```

Apache will check if %{REQUEST_URI} starts (`^`) with a directory name of nonzero length followed by a slash, then it will use the first match to see if a directory of that name exists witih `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/client/`. If so, the rewrite rule will apply whatever follows the slash (even nothing).

E.g. if the user requests the page

```
mydomain.com/sampleclient/orders
```

Apache will check if `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/client/sampleclient` exists and is a directory, and if so, it will load

```
mydomain.com/client/sampleclient/orders
```

Generally, it will load *mydomain.com/client/sampleclient/[whatever comes after the first slash]*.

If you don't need it to load `mydomain.com/client/sampleclient/orders` and want to apply the rewrite rules inside the `sampleclient` directory, use

```
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/(.*)$ /client/$1/ [QSA]
```

That is, remove the `$2` from the replace string, and the `L` flag inside square brackets.

See also [these Apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/remapping.html) for more info.

Comment: This works great for the subdirectories (/sampleclient/orders) but doesn't work on its own for the root directories (/sampleclient).  No big deal, I can just keep both rules in place.