# mod_rewrite check directory rule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2, directory

I have a url for ex :

```
example.com/site/anyFolderName
```

and i want to remap it to:

```
example.com/site/myfolder/anyFolderName
```

but only go there if 'anyFolderName' folder exists.I've searched in a few places for this but can't really figure it out.

#### Here's what i found out so far :

[Rewrite Condition to compare top level directory from Request_URI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115775/rewrite-condition-to-compare-top-level-directory-from-request-uri) - very similar with what i need but i have 2 levels

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/remapping.html #Search for pages in more than one directory

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the following to the `.htaccess` file in the root directory of your site.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase / 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/site/(\w+)$ [NC] 
#if site/myfolder/anyFolderName exists
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/site/myfolder/%1 -d
#rewrite request to site/myfolder/anyfolder
RewriteRule ^ site/myfolder/%1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: It works. Thanks you very much ! One more thing. In my URL it appears like example.com/site/myfolder/anyFolderName/. Is there any way to hide the myfolder from the link ? ex: example.com/site/anyFolderName